# Custom RSS formatting

Tags: rss

I have set up a custom rss template and all is working good but I am trying to figure out how to not show the image that is in the content. Is there a way to strip this out?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Custom Feed
*/


$numposts = 10;

function acustom_rss_date( $timestamp = null ) {
$timestamp = ($timestamp==null) ? time() : $timestamp;
echo date(DATE_RSS, $timestamp);
}

function acustom_rss_text_limit($string, $length, $replacer = '...') { 
 if(strlen($string) > $length) 
 return (preg_match('/^(.*)\W.*$/', substr($string, 0, $length+1), $matches)     ? $matches[1] : substr($string, 0, $length)) . $replacer;   
return $string; 
 }

$posts = query_posts('showposts='.$numposts);

$lastpost = $numposts - 1;

header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8");
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>';
?><rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss">
<channel>
<title>Site E-mail Update</title>
<link>http://www.example.com/</link>
<description>The latest posts from example.com</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<pubDate><?php acustom_rss_date( strtotime($ps[$lastpost]->post_date_gmt) );  ?></pubDate>
 <lastBuildDate><?php acustom_rss_date(    strtotime($ps[$lastpost]->post_date_gmt) ); ?></lastBuildDate>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) { ?>
  <item>
 <title><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></title>

  <link><?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?></link>
  <?php if(get_the_post_thumbnail()): ?>
   <media:content url="<?php $image =  wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium'); echo  $image[0]; ?>" medium="image" />
<?php endif; ?>
 <author> <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $post->post_author  ); ?></author>

  <description>


  <?php echo '<![CDATA['.acustom_rss_text_limit($post->post_content,  500).'<br/><br/><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'"> Continue Reading.  </a>'.']]>';  ?>



  </description>

  <pubDate><?php acustom_rss_date( strtotime($post->post_date_gmt) );  ?></pubDate>


  <guid><?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?></guid>
  </item>
 <?php } ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of this code

```
<?php if(get_the_post_thumbnail()): ?>
   <media:content url="<?php $image =  wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'medium'); echo  $image[0]; ?>" medium="image" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

That should remove the image associated with the post. It is checking to see if the featured image is set, and then if it is, it displays it. Removing the code, removes the image from display.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: Did this work for you? @sdesign